# How to pass CSV file object to falcon response

Tags: python-3.x, falconframework

```
csv_file = "test.csv"
with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(response_data)
    csvfile.close()
```

Here we have generated the CSV file locally. Now we are trying to create and download a file by using falcon. how can I pass a CSV file object to falcon response?

Answer (score 2):

You can serve your CSV file as follows:

Also, if you are using Falcon >= 1.4:

```
import falcon
import mimetypes


class StaticResource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        csv_file_path = "test.csv"
        resp.content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(csv_file_path)[0]
        resp.stream, resp.stream_len = open(csv_file_path)


app = falcon.API()
app.add_route('/static', StaticResource())
```

If you already created the file then create file object:

```
import falcon


class StaticResource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        csv_file_path = "test.csv"
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.content_type = 'text/csv'
        with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as f:
            resp.body = f.read()


app = falcon.API()
app.add_route('/static', StaticResource())
```

If you already have file object:

```
import falcon


class StaticResource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        csv_file_path = "test.csv"
        with open(csv_file_path, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(response_data)
            csvfile.close()
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.content_type = 'text/csv'
        resp.body = writer 


app = falcon.API()
app.add_route('/static', StaticResource())
```

I hope I answer your question correctly. Also, you can refer this document https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/api.html#falcon.API.add_static_route to serve directory.